# Communication through CAN-bus interface not working

Tags: python, linux, can-bus, buildroot, python-can

I have python code running on a linux based device which has the following OS specifications:

```
NAME=Buildroot
VERSION=2020.11.1
```

This device is connected to a PLC using a three wire interface (CAN_H,CAN_L,GND).

I have written a code that sends a message to the PLC using the CAN-bus protocol.  This is being done with the `python-can` package.

I have the following code:

```
import can

def send():
    #USB interface
    #bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate=500000)
    #on linux
    bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='socketcan', channel='vcan0', bitrate=500000)
    #on windows
    #bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='serial', channel='COM1', bitrate=500000)
    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x68005,data=[0x10,0x11,0x12],is_extended_id=True)
    try:
        bus.send(msg)
        print("Message sent on {}".format(bus.channel_info))
    except can.CanError:
        print("Message NOT sent")


if __name__ == '__main__':
     send()
```

The problem faced is that the device is not sending any data to the PLC. This is probably due to incorrect options set for `bustype` and `channel`.

Can anyone advise on what to provide for `bustype` and `channel` for this physical interface with three CAN wires?

Comment: Check the actual bus with your oscilloscope or CAN listener. What is getting sent there, if anything?

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING**: I'm not familiar with the python-can library, but I am with socketcan.

vcan0 is a virtual can channel that you can setup in order to enable virtual communication between applications (e.g. testing).

An actual CAN device (e.g. PCAN-USB) is listed as can0, can1, canX.
Beware that on some embedded systems this may not hold true (e.g. it can start with can1).

**EDIT**: I have forgotten to mention that you can get a list of all network interfaces like so, thus including CAN interfaces:

```
$ ifconfig -a
```

Reference documentation: https://elinux.org/Bringing_CAN_interface_up